# Does Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector work with Azure Functions?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I tried installing Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector with my Azure Functions. But it is not collecting any dependency data. Only when I use Custom events, I am able to get the dependency data. Is there any way to enable this tracking without writing custom code.

Answer (score 2):

It is a [known issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring#dependencies), you should always write custom code for dependency tracking in Azure Function:

> Dependencies that the function has to other services don't show up
>   automatically, but you can write custom code to show the dependencies.
>   The sample code in the [C# custom telemetry section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring#custom-telemetry-in-c-functions) shows how.

Answer (score 0):

Ivan Yangs anwser is correct for Azure Functions v1. Thankfully Microsft worked on that issue and made automatic dependency tracking available for Azure Functions v2 and v3 runtime.

Here you will find a comparison of what applications insights feature are supported by which Azure Function runtime:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/azure-functions-supported-features